# Random song playing app improvements

Tags: java, algorithm, directory

I have a substantial music collection, which will not load entirely in any music program.

So I wrote this quick program, to play a random song in a subfolder of my music directory.

I'm just wondering if anyone can improve on this code? It works pretty well, but the subdirectories are not all equal with respect to size, so it neglects some directories. My random mod might also be a problem. This is just to have a useful shuffle.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Pick {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    File f = new File("C:\\MUSIC");
    File random = null;
    try {
        random = goDeeper(f);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    while (random == null) {
        try {
            random = goDeeper(f);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    System.out.println(random.getAbsolutePath());
    Process myProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
            "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\foobar2000\\foobar2000.exe\"   \""
                    + random.getAbsolutePath() + "\"  ");

}

public static File goDeeper(File f) {
    File[] children = f.listFiles();

    int rand = (int) ((Math.random() * 123456) % children.length);
    File random = children[rand];
    if (random.isDirectory()) {
        return goDeeper(new File(f.getAbsolutePath() + "/"
                + random.getName()));
    } else if (random.isFile() && random.getName().endsWith("mp3"))
        return random.getAbsoluteFile();

    return null;
}

}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Don't repeat yourself**

The `try-random-catch` block appears two times in your code. The easiest way to fix this would be to delete the first occurrence. You don't need it, as the while check will be true on the first loop, thus executing that block.

**Handling Exceptions**

There are a lot of ways to handle an exception, but just silently ignoring it is not one of them. It will make it very hard to find bugs.

Alternatives are:

- just let the exception bubble up all the way
- log the exception to a file (for detailed information use `getStackTrace`)
- print the exception to console (best use `printStackTrace`, not `getMessage`)
- handle the exception

It is also important to not catch a blanket `Exception`, but the specific exceptions that may be thrown. With your code, a reader doesn't really know what *might* be thrown (and thus has no idea at all what might have gone wrong).

**Random file selection**

Your selection process isn't really random.

1. Let's say you have structure like this:

   > ```
   > /
   > /dir
   > /song.mp3
   > /dir/nonMp3File
   > /dir/anotherSong.mp3
   > ```

Now, we enter `goDeeper`, and randomly select `dir`. On the next iteration, we randomly select `nonMp3File`. Now, null is returned and we restart at `/`. That means if you have a lot of non-mp3 files in you music folder (cover art, etc), the deeper nested the file, the less likely it will be that it will be selected, because the `goDeeper` returned null first.

2. Even if you fix 1., your program will still favor songs that are less deeply nested inside subdirectories.

This might not be a bad thing (it depends on the structure of your music directory, and how you want to select) though.

3. the hardcoded `123456` lets me suspect that you are not really randomly selecting among the children. Something like `rand = new Random().nextInt(children.length + 1);` might be better.

**Infinite loop**

If you don't have any MP3 files, the program will loop forever. If the ratio of MP3 to non-MP3 is bad, the program might loop for a long time before playing a song.

**Naming**

- `random` might be `randomFileName` (both in main and `goDeeper`).
- `f` might be `baseDirectory` (for the variable as well as the parameter).
- `goDeeper` might be `getRandomFileName`.

**Misc**

- Use curly braces, even for one-line statements to avoid bugs and to increase readability.
- Remove unused variables: you are never using `myProcess`, so just remove it (not the call to exec, just the variable declaration).

Comment: thanks, changed some of the things... should new Random().nextInt(children.length + 1) have the + 1?

Comment: @djb no, it shouldn't. `nextInt` returns a range from `0` to the specified value (exclusively, this is why I added +1). But we only want to go to `length - 1`, so the +1 is indeed wrong, thanks. Also, I rolled back your edit, please see [What you can and cannot do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765).

Comment: What's the difference between logging exception and printing it? And do you mean `printStackTrace()` ?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg with logging I meant writing to a file. And yes, I did mean `printStackTrace`, thanks. I clarified my answer.

Comment: If using logging, then log4j is a good framework, and that can accept a `Throwable` object directly, so often it's not needed to use `getStackTrace`. Also, the `printStackTrace` method can take a writer as argument to write to a specific stream (such as a `FileOutputStream`).

Answer (score 3):

About this:

```
return goDeeper(new File(f.getAbsolutePath() + "/"
            + random.getName()));
```

A more prefered way of constructing a new `File` object is:

```
new File(f, random.getName());
```

But wait a minute... That is exactly the same file as `random` in the first place.

```
new File(random);
```

But as you're just creating a new file object for the same file, you don't really need to create a new file object at all, just use it directly.

```
return goDeeper(random);
```

Comment: oh yeah, good catch